# git clone SSL protocol error

Tags: windows, git, ssl

I am trying to clone a git from a remote server in windows 7.

```
curl -v https://myserver
```

works `git clone` I get a:

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://myserver': Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to myserver:8080
```

another user using my computer was able to do it though. It's only my account that doesn't work?

any ideas?

thanks

Comment: What kind of git server you use? Can you access to the repository using web interface?

Comment: a local bitbucket. I can get to the server via the website fine. It's just the neither sourcetree nor bash can clone repos for my account. Other users seems fine

Comment: Have you taken the URL from Bitbucket GUI? Are you sure https is configured in your Bitbucket server? Can you publish the URL you use (just replace the sensible values)?

Comment: I dont think it's the server. Another user using my computer was about to git clone. it is just my user account